# K3S Rancher - Debian based docker images not resolving dns properly

Tags: networking, kubernetes, dns, resolve, k3s

I am facing strange problem.

What I've done:

I deployed **Rancher K3S** cluster and there is a problem in dns resolving with debian based images. Domains are not resolved properly - it adds suffix to it with one of ours domain.

What I've found:

**Debian based image** adds suffix with domain to the end. e.g. I ping google.com and its pinging google.com.example.com. (example.com is one of our domains - not specifing it because it is not important imo)

The same for curl google.com makes request to ip address of example.com . Even tried pure debian image and it is still doing the same issue.

**Alpine based images** works fine (ping to google.com pings google.com, nslookup shows right ip address).

**Host server** where k3s is installed also works fine (redhat os). Ping to google.com pings google.com.

Some additional data that can maybe help you:

**CoreDNS configmap**
kubectl -n kube-system get configmap coredns -o go-template={{.data.Corefile}}

```
.:53 {
    errors
    health
    ready
    kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
      pods insecure
      upstream
      fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
    }
    hosts /etc/coredns/NodeHosts {
      reload 1s
      fallthrough
    }
    prometheus :9153
    forward . 8.8.8.8
    cache 30
    loop
    reload
    loadbalance
}
```

Does anyone faced the same or similar problem?
Do you have some points to push me towards solving?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issues with `k3s` (v.v1.19.3+k3s3) on `centos` 8 (not quite sure it has anything to do with the images' OS, though). `k3s` is a bit less plug and play that other distro like `microk8s`.

### Use local DNS parameter

On each node, you could say that you want to use the host's resolv parameters. If `k3s` is managed as **systemd service** (which is probably the case), you could just edit `/etc/systemd/system/k3s.service.env` to add you system's `resolv.conf`

```
K3S_RESOLV_CONF=/etc/resolv.conf
```

and then restart the service

```sh
sudo systemctl status k3s
```

- **plus**: the easiest solution, easily scriptable
- **cons**: you'll need to do it on each of your nodes (from what I understand). Different `resolv.conf` on different systems involves that the very same deployment might not act the same way depending on the nodes used by kube

[relevant documentation](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/install-options/agent-config/#networking)

### Use Global DNS

Haven't tried but here is [the doc](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/helm-charts/legacy-catalogs/globaldns/)